# In PostgreSQL, how can I get the máximum value for which all previous values satisfy a condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table which records the test results of different students:

```
Student  Exam Passed
A        1    True
A        2    True
A        3    False
A        4    True
B        1    False
B        2    True
```

What I'd like to get is the maximum exam value for which all previous exams values are true. For example, in case of student A it would be 2 (not 4, because value un exam 3 is true) and for student B it would be zero, given that level 1 is false

```
Student     Maximum level
A           2
B           0
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by student and find the first `exam` with `Passed = False`:

```
select
  student,
  coalesce(min(case when not passed then exam end) - 1, max(exam)) as "Maximum level"
from tablename
group by student
order by student
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e5F7kqv7JLdTm9wkLx5Nrc/2).
Results:

```
| student | Maximum level |
| ------- | ------------- |
| A       | 2             |
| B       | 0             |
```